# How can i create CRUD app in Angular 6 with local mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, angular6

I am confuse that how to create basic CRUD in angular with mongoDB. i install mongodb and create database but i don't know where is my database created. How can i connect my DB with angular 6 and how can i INSERT , UPDATE and DELETE record. other confusion is about models . where is model created and how to call that models in order to interact with db. i am very beginner in Angular 6 and mongoDB. Please guide me step by step. i searched a lots but not find something valuable.
Answers and suggestion will be highly appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect directly any DB and can't do CRUD operation with angular. If you achieve CRUD in angular you need to create API in any server-side language such as PHP,.net, java, node.js and any other. After that, you can call API using `HttpClient` and achieve CRUD functionality. You can learn more to [Clik here to learn HttPClient method for calling API](https://angular.io/guide/http)